# Use the same AppWidgetAdapter on multiple widgets / copy the class in a smart way

Tags: java, android, inheritance, widget, copy

I'm creating two different versions of a widget in my app, which differs in the layout only, the class/methods being the same. However, android doesn't accept two widget with the same`AppWidgetProvider` as name. So, I have to make them different:

```
 <receiver
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/widget_name_vert"
                android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/widget_info_vert" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/widget_name_horz"
                android:name="MyWidgetProviderCopy" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/widget_info_horz" />
        </receiver>
```

What's the most efficient way to make `MyWidgetProviderCopy` the same as `MyWidgetProvider`, so I could only update one for both? I am learning java as I have my way with android, so there might be some smart way I am unaware of. I tried extending the class like

```
Public class MyWidgetProviderCopy extends MyWidgetProvider {
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, or I am doing something wrong.
Thanks for any help or input.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a base class that extends `AppWidgetProvider`, then have classes that extend from it (one for each version of your AppWidget).

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class in Java, the subclass will inherit all public and protected methods and fields. It will not, however, inherit any private methods or fields. The only way to have the subclass have access to these fields is by creating public methods in the base class that allow you access to those private fields

```
Public class Example{ 

    private String exampleString;

    public String getExampleString(){
        return exampleString;
    }
}
```

Then, if this class is extended by another class, that subclass will be able to access the private string `example` by using the `getExample` method.

Also, to access any private methods, you can create a public wrapper method that just calls the method you want to use.

```
Public class Example2{
    private void exampleMethod(){}

    public void exampleMethodWrapper(){
        exampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Thus, you can do what you have listed, but you may need to make changes to your base class so that the subclass can access all of the fields and methods properly.

Comment: Couldn't you also create protected wrapper methods so the general public can't access the wrappers but the subclass can?

Comment: Yes, protected could also be used to allow subclasses to use both fields and methods without letting the general public access them.